# Hudson CI exception after build script execution for iOS

Tags: ios, macos, shell, hudson, jna

I am getting following exception during automation build execution with Hudson CI. This exception comes after build script completes the build job and because of this exception post build task does not able to get performed. I have tried with with different MAC systems.

```
FATAL: org.hudsonci.plugins.jna.JnaNativeMacSupport$NativeMacProcess$1StringArrayMemory.getSize()J
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hudsonci.plugins.jna.JnaNativeMacSupport$NativeMacProcess$1StringArrayMemory.getSize()J
    at org.hudsonci.plugins.jna.JnaNativeMacSupport$NativeMacProcess$1StringArrayMemory.hasMore(JnaNativeMacSupport.java:199)
    at org.hudsonci.plugins.jna.JnaNativeMacSupport$NativeMacProcess$1StringArrayMemory.readString(JnaNativeMacSupport.java:209)
    at org.hudsonci.plugins.jna.JnaNativeMacSupport$NativeMacProcess.parse(JnaNativeMacSupport.java:258)
    at org.hudsonci.plugins.jna.JnaNativeMacSupport$NativeMacProcess.getEnvironmentVariables(JnaNativeMacSupport.java:172)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Darwin$DarwinProcess.getEnvironmentVariables(ProcessTree.java:962)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$OSProcess.hasMatchingEnvVars(ProcessTree.java:256)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:504)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:670)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:549)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1450)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
```

Is there any issue with JNA native access?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like `jna` (whatever that is) can't read some environment variable cause it can't figure out it's size.